# Setting up typescript using gulp-typescript results in multiple errors

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

Hi I am trying to configure gulp to compile my typescript files here is what I have so far:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const util = require('gulp-util');

var paths = {
   npmSrc: "./node_modules/",
   libTarget: "./wwwroot/lib/",
   appTarget: "./wwwroot/app/"
}

gulp.task('tsBuild', function () {

    return gulp.src('App/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(typescript(tscConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.appTarget));
}
```

My tsConfig looks like this:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/app/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

This are the error messages I am getting:

> App\bootstrap.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
>
> App\template\template.component.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile
> modules unless the '--module' flag is provided with a valid module
> type. Consider setting the 'module' compiler option in a
> 'tsconfig.json' file.
>
> > App\template\template.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'. App\template\template.component.ts(8,14):
>
> error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is
> subject to change in a future release. Set the
> 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

It feels as if it is not reading the tsconfig file.My files do eventually get compiled correctly.

.Anyone has any ideea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is gulp task that should work fine:

```
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');   

gulp.task('tsBuild', function () 
{
    var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject));  

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.appTarget));
});
```

Its always easier to exclude unnecessary files in tsconfig instead of explicitly specifying all necessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions;
```